# Dealing with race condition in transactional database table

Tags: database, race-condition

Let me lay the scenario out first.  Say you have a database for a business app and one of the things it tracks is inventory.  The system says you have 5 screws in stock.  Say you needed all 5.  The system creates an inventory transaction record for -5.  After you commit that transaction, since you know you had 5 before and you pulled out 5, if you sum up all the inventory transaction records for that screw the total should be 0.  The problem occurs when two people are trying to do this at the same time.  Say one person wants 4 and the other wants 2.  Both client apps check the quantity beforehand and they are both told 5.  At the exact same time one creates a transaction for -4 and the other for -2.  The results in the total inventory quantity to be -1 which should never be possible because the system should not allow negative inventory.

How would you solve this if you didn't have a server application to help you?  I mention that because a server coordinating the inventory transactions is how I would solve it but right now our product has no server application.  We just have client apps which talk to a Firebird database directly.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this with just the client apps and database.  One thing that might help is that Firebird has something called a Generator which is basically a unique number generator that is atomic so you are guaranteed that if you asked Firebird to increment the generator and give you the next number that it will not give anyone else that same number.

My mind was going down the route of trying to create a makeshift record lock using a generator.  I thought I could have them both check a "lock" field on the Item table.  If it is null, then noone has a lock.  If it is non-null it is locked so you need to keep checking back until it is not locked.  If there is no lock you ask the generator for a uniq number and store that in the locking field for the Item you want to lock.  You commit that transaction then go back and check to see if it is indeed the case that the Item table's lock field contains the number you put there.  If it does then you have successfully locked and if it doesn't then that means someone was locking it at the same time and you lost the race.  Once you are done you null out the lock and the client that is waiting will then see the null, lock it themselves and repeat.

This itself has a race condition I believe though.  Trxn1 (transaction 1) checks lock and finds null.  Trxn2 checks lock and finds null.  Trxn1 gets new lock number from generator.  Trxn2 gets new lock from generator.  Trxn1 says update Item record with my lock if lock is still null which it is.  Trxn1 commits trxn then starts a new Trxn1 and proves the lock contains his lock id and it does so it knows it has permission to make inventory transactions and it starts doing so.  Right after Trxn1 checks to see if it got the lock Trxn2 commits its update statement that stored its lock if the lock was null.  If Trxn2 executed his update statement before Trxn1 committed the lock then Trxn2 would still see the value as null and the update would occur.  If Trxn2's lock commit happens after Trxn1 committed lock and already verified it we have a problem.  Trxn1 is making changes to Item transaction table.  Trxn2 got his lock committed because the lock was null in its transaction world when it did it and when it commits Trxn2's update statement will overwrite Trxn1's lock because the null check in the update statement happened before both committed, not at the time of commit.  So now both think they have a lock and we will end up with negative inventory.

Can anyone think of a way to solve this short of having a server application with some kind of queueing system (FIFO)?  I would prefer if it could all be done via clients "talking to the database" to coordinate this but that may not be possible technically speaking.  Sorry If this got a bit wordy :D

Solution Edit:
jtahlborn seems to have the right idea.  I somehow didn't realize that Firebird does in fact have row level locking.  Simple select statements (no joins, group by, etc) can have "with lock" appended to the end of the statement and any row returned by the statement will be locked until the transaction is committed or rolled back.  Noone else can obtain a lock on that row nor make changes to it.  Because I don't want to lock the entire ITEM table while I'm inserting rows in to the Item transaction table, I am going to create a table just for locking that has one column (the ItemID field).  Because the second transaction will get an error when it tries to do it's own lock, it doesn't matter that I am never actually modifying anything on the locking table itself.  Failing to get a lock gives me all the information I need.  I will put triggers on the insert / delete of the ITEM table so that for every Item record this is also a record in the ITEMLOCK table.  Here is the process I'm going to use.

1. Start database transaction
2. Attempted to obtain lock on ITEMLOCK row with the ItemID of the Item you want to change
3. If you can't get a lock keep trying until the record is unlocked
4. Once locked go prove that the quantity on hand of that Item is enough to cover what you
5. want to take out, because they could have old data this might not be
   the case and it will drop out here and message the user
6. If sufficient quantities exist insert your inventory transaction record in the inventory transaction table
7. Commit transaction which in turn releases the lock

Note:  Matthieu M mentioned the FOR UPDATE clause.  It is mentioned in the documentation along with the WITH LOCK clause.  As I understand it you can use that when you are locking multiple rows with one statement.  I am not one hundred percent sure, but it seems like doing this with WITH LOCK will trying an all or nothing approach and FOR UPDATE will lock each one separately one at a time.  I am not sure what happens if it locked the first 100 records you asked for but on the 101th record it couldn't get a lock.  Does it then release the 100 locks you did get?  I will need to lock more than one Item at a time, but I do not feel comfortable with FOR UPDATE since I feel like I don't truly understand the difference.  I also probably want to know which Item was already locked for user messaging purposes (going to put a timeout so trxns wont wait forever for a lock) so I will be locking one at at time using WITH LOCK.

Note 2:  I want to point out to anyone using this in their own code to be careful.  I am going to have a very simple loop when waiting for a lock to be released (is it released yet? how about now? now?).  If I had a ton of users possibly trying to lock the same row at the same time there may be a deadlock scenario.  Say you have a slow client.  That client may always end up with the short end of the stick because every time the lock was release some other client then grabbed it faster than the slow client could.  If this happened over and over this would be essentially a deadlock scenario.  If I was worried about that I would need a way to figure out who is first in line.  In my case, database transactions should be short lived, we never have more than 50 users (not a cloud system), and it is highly unlikely that they all are using this part of the system at the same time trying to modify the exact same Item's inventory quantity.

Comment: add a column (or columns) with a forgein key pointing to the previous transaction. Then add a unique constraint to this column. Now the database will enforce that no 2 transactions can point to the same previous transaction causing all transactions to be serialized.

Comment: You should read about [select for update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935850/when-to-use-select-for-update).

Comment: You cannot lock a non existing row with select for update.

Comment: Interesting idea JoG.  I think I have a better solution, but this is certainly a creative way to solve the problem and it sounds like it would work as well.

Comment: you can even take it a step further and keep totals in the records next to the change amount. so you have changeamount, total, previoustotal and then u can add constraints that total = previoustotal + change. This way you can keep a full history of all the transactions and just lookup the totals by looking at the latest  transaction avoiding aggregate queries over a large amount of transactions.

Comment: I would make the total amount visible to the system in some way and put a constraint on that column that the value be > 0. When the first transaction completes it will be positive, but the second one will cause a constraint violation and the transaction will be aborted. Catch the failure in your client code and tell the user you're out of that product. This does require a coordinating database server, but that is why we call them "database _management_ systems."

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, instead of part of the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to lock some primary row (like the main "item") and use this as your distributed locking mechanism.  (assuming your database supports row-level locks, as most modern dbs do).

Comment: Or in SQL: `select ... from ... where ... FOR UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up about the CAP theorem and how it may be an explanation for the scenario you are describing. EDIT: Having read in more detail, my comment may be of limited use because it seems you already know this and are trying to solve the problem within Firebird.