# Django when looping over a queryset, when does the db read happen?

Tags: django, sqlite, for-loop, django-orm

I am looping through my database and updating all my `Company` objects.

```
for company in Company.objects.filter(updated=False):
    driver.get(company.company_url)
    company.adress = driver.find_element_by_id("address").text
    company.visited = True    
    company.save()
```

My problem is that it's taking too long so I wanted to run another instance of this same code, but I'm curious when the actual db reads happen. If  `company.visited` get's changed to `True` while this loop is running, will still be visited by this loop? What if I added a second check for `visited`? I don't want to start a second loop if the first instance isn't going to recognize the work of the second instance:

```
for company in Company.objects.filter(updated=False):
    if company.visited:
        continue
    driver.get(company.company_url)
    company.adress = driver.find_element_by_id("address").text
    company.visited = True    
    company.save()
```

Comment: Is this code executed inside a view, inside a celery task or somewhere else?

Comment: This code is being kicked off from `manage.py shell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Company.objects.filter(updated=False)` translates to an ordinary SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM appName_company WHERE updated is false
```

This SQL query is executed when you start iterating through `Company` objects. It's executed only once. The second server will not recognize the work of the first one, because they both will go through the same `Company` objects.

Lock rows to avoid race conditions using atomic transactions and `select_for_update()`:

```
from django.db import transaction

for company in Company.objects.filter(updated=False):
    with transaction.atomic():
        Company.objects.select_for_update().get(id=company.id)
        if company.visited:
            continue
        driver.get(company.company_url)
        company.adress = driver.find_element_by_id("address").text
        company.visited = True    
        company.save()
```

You can run this code on multiple servers. Each `Company` will be processed just once.

If you need to execute this code regularly, I highly recommend using Celery. Dispatch a task per each company, and let multiple workers do the work in parallel:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def dispatch_tasks():
    for company in Company.objects.filter(updated=False):
        process_company.delay(company.id)

@shared_task
@transaction.atomic
def process_company(company_id):
    company = Company.objects.select_for_update().get(id=company_id)
    if company.visited:
        continue
    driver.get(company.company_url)
    company.adress = driver.find_element_by_id("address").text
    company.visited = True    
    company.save()
```

---

Edit: oh, I see that you've tagged the question with the sqlite tag. I recommend switching to PostgreSQL, as SQLite is really bad at concurrency. My answer should work with SQlite, but locks may slow down the database.

Comment: `select_for_update()`is ignored on SQLite: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#queryset-select-for-update-not-supported
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949541/1097104