# What is the difference between Cursor For update and general update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I would like to understand the difference between these different code snippets in SQL Server and also would like to know which one performs well in PROD bulk updates Scenario...Please check and advice...Thank you in advance for your time and valuable inputs in this regard.

**Snippet 1** :

```sql
  DECLARE @EmpID
    
  DECLARE C_XML2 CURSOR LOCAL FOR  SELECT emp_code FROM r5employees WHERE emp_status = 'A' 
  AND emp_class = 'EMP' AND emp_location IS NULL FOR UPDATE
  
  BEGIN
      OPEN C_XML2
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_XML2 into @EmpID
      
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
      BEGIN
          UPDATE r5employees SET emp_status = 'NA' WHERE emp_status = 'A' 
          AND emp_class = 'EMP' AND emp_location IS NULL AND emp_code = @EmpID
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_XML2 into @EmpID
  END
  CLOSE C_XML2
  DEALLOCATE C_XML2
  END
```

**Snippet 2**

```sql
DECLARE @EmpID
    
  DECLARE C_XML2 CURSOR LOCAL FOR  SELECT emp_code FROM r5employees WHERE emp_status = 'A' 
  AND emp_class = 'EMP' AND emp_location IS NULL 
  
  BEGIN
      OPEN C_XML2
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_XML2 into @EmpID
      
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
      BEGIN
          UPDATE r5employees SET emp_status = 'NA' WHERE emp_status = 'A' 
          AND emp_class = 'EMP' AND emp_location IS NULL WHERE UPDATE OF C_XML2
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_XML2 into @EmpID
  END
  CLOSE C_XML2
  DEALLOCATE C_XML2
  END
```

**Snippet 3**

```sql
DECLARE @EmpID
    
  DECLARE C_XML2 CURSOR LOCAL FOR  SELECT emp_code FROM r5employees WHERE emp_status = 'A' 
  AND emp_class = 'EMP' AND emp_location IS NULL 
  
  BEGIN
      OPEN C_XML2
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_XML2 into @EmpID
      
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
      BEGIN
          UPDATE r5employees SET emp_status = 'NA' WHERE emp_status = 'A' 
          AND emp_class = 'EMP' AND emp_location IS NULL 
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_XML2 into @EmpID
  END
  CLOSE C_XML2
  DEALLOCATE C_XML2
  END
```

Comment: To be honest, all 3 snippets look pretty bad, i think you misunderstand how cursors work. Also, for your code examples, why do you need cursors at all, just perform the UPDATE normally and be done with it

Comment: Thank you for your quick response...! However does For Update simply locks all the tables involved ? Please check and advice...Thanks

Comment: I can't even see the difference between the 3 options. You might want to point them out

Comment: Thank you...Actually I'm not very much familiar with SQL Server Coding and hence looking for your advice.... Does direct update statement execution fires Row Level triggers or only Statement Level Triggers only ? Also I'm not sure whether we have Row Level and Statmenet Leven triggers in SQL Server like in Oracle...Please advice...Thanks

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? SQL server doesn't have row level triggers.

Comment: Partially duplicate with: [When to use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935850/when-to-use-select-for-update)

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using? None of the snippets have completely valid syntax for Microsoft SQL Server. e.g.: `WHERE UPDATE OF C_XML2`?

Comment: Of the three snippets (after correcting for syntax errors) the first one is the only one most likely to work as expected - it's the only one that actually uses the `@EmpID` from the cursor to perform a correlated update on the target table.

Comment: RTFM. to answer your question what is a difference https://techie-friendly.blogspot.com/2014/05/local-and-global-cursors-in-sql-server.html